# ruby mine debug error :failed to install gems

Tags: ruby, remote-debugging, rubymine

While trying debugging on RubyMine-7.0.2 IDE in RHEL 6.2 environment , I am getting below error.

```
failed to install gems. following gems were not installed.
/home/john/RubyMine-7.0.2/rb/gems/ruby-debug-base-0.10.5.rc10.gem: Error installing ruby-debug-base-0.10.5.rc10.gem.
ERROR:Failed to build gem native extension./usr/bin/ruby exconf.rb Ruby version 1.9.2 is too new *** exconf.rb failed 
couldnot create makefile due to some reason. probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log file for more details. you may need configuration options. provided onfiguration reason. probably lack of neessary libraries and/or headers. check the mkmf.log file for more details.
```

apart from this when I tried to install gems by executing below command , I got error like

```
_-bash: aptitude command not found.
-bash:apt-get command not found.
```

Command to install rubygems.

```
aptitude install libgemplugin-ruby
apt-get install libgemplugin-ruby
```

I will appreciate if some one can help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the `Ubuntu` package utility (`apt` / `aptitude`) in a RHEL box. Just follow the right tutorial, such as [this one](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/RubyGems#RedHat_Linux), to install rubygems:

```
yum install rubygems
```

Comment: This was the first command which I tried earlier  and then decided to execute  above mentioned  commands as it doesn't work on my machine.

Comment: *it doesn't work on my machine* -> is ``yum`` installed? is it giving you an error? which one?